# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server

Tags: linux, apache, linux-mint

Установил apache на linux mint, при просмотре статуса Apache вылезает такая ошибка, помогите разобраться в проблеме.

```
    ● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-10-15 20:18:03 +07; 10min ago
  Process: 5060 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: Action 'start' failed.
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint apachectl[5060]: The Apache error log may have more information.
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
окт 15 20:18:03 my-mint systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Куча ошибок, главная - кто-то сидит на 80 порту. `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep :80` в студию. netstat входит в nettools, если еще не стоит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apachectl[5060]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

Ошибка говорит о том, что 80 порт уже занят. 
Остановите службу, которая занимает порт. Для проверки:

```
sudo netstat -tpln | grep ":80"
```

Либо в конфиге apache2 смените порт на другой.

Answer (score 3):

Сменил порт на другой в файле `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` в строке `Listen 80`